# How can I use Redux Saga "call" function when the function name is a reserved word and how do I do chained function calls?

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux-saga, method-call

```
 yield action.user.delete() && database.ref(url).remove()
```

I need to use `call()` in both functions in redux-sagas using Firebase functions. In `action.user.delete()`, I can't do 
`yield {delete} = action.user` or `call([action.user, delete])`, because `delete` is a reserved word. And in `database.ref(url).remove()`, I don't know how to use `call()` for chained functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple syntax options for dealing with `delete` being a reserved word:

- Pass a string for the function name to the `call` method
- Get a reference to the `delete` function in a variable with a different name

Both options are shown below.

For chained functions, you just split the chain into the separate calls and use the result from one call to execute the next call. I have included an example of doing chained calls after the two `delete` examples.

```
import { call } from "redux-saga/effects";

const refResponse = {
  remove: () => {
    console.log("You removed me!");
  }
};
const action = {
  user: {
    delete: () => {
      console.log("You deleted me!");
    }
  }
};
const database = {
  ref: () => {
    console.log("Returning ref");
    return refResponse;
  }
};
export const starter = function*() {
  console.log("before call");
  yield call([action.user, "delete"]);
  console.log("after call using string for function name");
  const deleteFunc = action.user.delete;
  yield call([action.user, deleteFunc]);
  console.log("after call using function variable");

  console.log("before start of chained call");
  const result = yield call([database, "ref"]);
  console.log("before 2nd part of chained call");
  yield call([result, "remove"]);
};
```

[image: Edit 9470nnlwmy]

Comment: sorry, but it does not work for me.. I got it done using `const {ref} =database
  const {remove} = database.ref()
  const result = yield call([database, ref], url)
  yield call([result, remove])` and  `const deleteFunction = () => action.user.delete()
yield call([action.user, deleteFunction])`, but I thank you for your help, big hug.